# Add X-Content-Type-Options No Sniff

Tags: java, jsp, spring-security, http-headers, security

I am currently trying to implement more security measures for my java application and have encountered the suggestion of using the x-content-type-options no sniff.  Upon my searching I was unable to find any ways to implement this feature.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Spring, you can try -

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean id="webContentInterceptor" 
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
        <property name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff"/>
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Comment: I apologize in advance if this question seems silly.  But does this implementation work in Tomcat?  And if so, where would it need to be in the application?

Comment: @DD84 - It should work in Tomcat. Try putting it in /WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml

Comment: you can put in jsp if you are using one.. or you can extend the default filter and append this header and continue the filter chain.

Comment: How to do this using `annotations`?